# BCrypt: What do we mean by 'the number of rounds to process data'?

Tags: node.js, authentication, bcrypt

I have recently been looking into BCrypt, but don't seem to quite understand what we mean by `rounds` in the following.

`genSalt(rounds, callback)`

The documentation states that it is the number of rounds taken to process the data... but what does that mean? Is it the number of times the data is being hashed continuously? If so, what algorithm is being used?

[ ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs ]

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs] gave me 400 Bad Request.

Comment: without the ']' at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`round` in `genSalt` and `genSaltSync` only affects the work factor in its output. It means when hashing, the input will be hashed 2<sup>rounds</sup> times. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Blowfish-based_scheme.